# Split crystal report text field with more than one delimiter and load on different field

Tags: c#, arrays, split, crystal-reports, delimiter

I have saved the following text which represent patient prescription in a table field ABZ SYP 10MLS-5-40-1-b.d-5-10-400,ABZ TAB 400MG-10-5-0.5-t.i.d-10-30-75, and I don't want it to load in a single crystal report field. I want them to be loaded in different fields like
first split on comma, like below

```
ABZ SYP 10MLS-5-40-1-b.d-5-10-400,
ABZ TAB 400MG-10-5-0.5-t.i.d-10-30-75,
ACTAL SYP 5LITRES-6-50-1-o.d-10-10-500,
```

then split on hyphen - and have below final output on different fields
ABZ SYP 10MLS  unit cost 40 1 frequency b.d qty 5 days 10  cost 400
ABZ TAB 400MG unit cost 5 unit 0.5 frequency t.i.d qty 10 days 30 cost 75

below is my code can't seem to make it work

```
stringvar array MYARRAY:=  Split({Table.Treatment}, "-");
stringvar array numbers;`enter code here`
Redim numbers[Ubound(MYARRAY)];
numberVar i ;
  for i :=1  to ubound(MYARRAY)   do  (
//MYARRAY[1][i] //&" "& MYARRAY[5][i]&" "& MYARRAY[6][i]&" Days,";
//numbers[i] := (MYARRAY[1]) &" "& (MYARRAY[5])&" "& (MYARRAY[6])&" Days,"
//numbers[i] := Tostring(MYARRAY[1][i])
);
 // 
numbers;
```

Comment: use a space " " split character  to get your string in 3 parts. "ABZ" , "SYP" and "10MLS......" then split the third one with "-" this will give you "10MLS", "10", "5", "0.5", "t.i.d", "10", "30", "75" then create your new string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for responses i was able to yield the results i needed by adjusting code as follows with help of your responses

```
    local stringvar array MYARRAY:=  Split({Table.Treatment}, ",");
numberVar i ;
 Stringvar output;
 //output:
  for i :=1  to ubound(MYARRAY)   do  (
Stringvar array AfterSplit2:=Split(MYARRAY[i], "-");
output:=output + AfterSplit2[1] & space(1)& AfterSplit2[5] &" Days "& AfterSplit2[6]&" Qty "& AfterSplit2[7] & ChrW(10)
);
output
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8MvV.png)

Answer (score 0):

With the sample data that you have posted I see a pattern in the data which can be used to split all of the data.

```
ABZ SYP 10MLS-5-40-1-b.d-5-10-400
```

1st Delimiter **Space**

2nd Delimiter **.**

3rd Delimiter **-**

So your code should be like first split by **Space** then by **.** and then by **-**

```
Local stringvar array MYARRAY:=  Split("ABZ SYP 10MLS-5-40-1-b.d-5-10-400", " ");
Local Strngvar array AfterSplit1:=Split(MYARRAY[3], ".");;
Local Strngvar array AfterSplit2:=Split(AfterSplit1[1], "-");
Local Strngvar array AfterSplit3:=Split(AfterSplit1[2], "-");


                                //output:

MYARRAY[1]& ChrW(13) &             //ABC
MYARRAY[2]&  ChrW(13) &           //SYP 
AfterSplit2[1]& ChrW(13) &         //10MLS
AfterSplit2[2]& ChrW(13) &           //5
AfterSplit2[3]& ChrW(13) &         //40
AfterSplit2[3]& ChrW(13) &         //1
AfterSplit2[4]& ChrW(13) &         //b
AfterSplit3[1]& ChrW(13) &          //d
AfterSplit3[2]& ChrW(13) &           //5
AfterSplit3[3]& ChrW(13) &          //10 
AfterSplit3[4]                      //400
```

I didn't have the tool right now so unable to test for errors but sure this will work

Try and let me know

Comment: thank you for responses i was able to yield the results i needed by adjusting code as follows                                                                     local stringvar array MYARRAY:=  Split({Table.Treatment}, ",");
numberVar i ;
 Stringvar output;
 //output:
  for i :=1  to ubound(MYARRAY)   do  (
Stringvar array AfterSplit2:=Split(MYARRAY[i], "-");
output:=output + AfterSplit2[1] & space(1)& AfterSplit2[5] &" Days "& AfterSplit2[6]&" Qty "& AfterSplit2[7] & ChrW(10)
);
output

Comment: @DennisMutwiri No Problem you can accept it as answered if it worked for you... So that others can use